# Is it possible to show "all calls" on my Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, call-history

Under phone -> logs -> menu key -> view by there are options for all logs, dialled calls, missed calls, received calls, sent messages and received messages.

Is it possible to show "all calls" instead?

Is this more of a feature request than an answerable question?

Answer (score 1):

There's an "all calls" option in "Call History" on my phone. (Running 2.2 but on a HTC with their UI, which may be different, as pointed out below.)

When I hit "view", the option buttons are:

1. All Calls
2. Incoming Calls
3. Outgoing calls
4. Missed calls

Is this what you're after, or have I mis-interpreted your question?

Comment: I'm not sure what phone you've got, but it sounds like you don't have a Samsung? It sounds like your one doesn't have Samsung's TouchWiz interface, but possibly has a different interface, like HTC's Sense?

Comment: You are correct, I didn't take that into account. I have a Desire HD with HTC sense.